# awk - print overlapping ranges

Tags: awk, overlapping-matches, numeric-ranges

I'm afraid I haven't come across a direct way of doing this, although I tried adapting some provided solutions for similar scenarios (but not quite for what I need). Given this data:

```
1118 1120
1121 1124
1122 1127
1125 1126
1128 1133
1130 1135
1136 1139
1137 1138
1140 1145
```

It is already sorted by column 1. Except for first and last lines, all the others have intervals that overlap, in pairs. So I want an output with just the overlapping ranges:

```
1122 1124
1125 1126
1130 1133
1137 1138
```

For me at least, this is harder that I expected at first glance.

Comment: `tried adapting some provided solutions` please do add that to question... it will show your effort... else likely the question would be treated as asking free coding service..

Comment: why should `1122 1127` not be in the output?

Comment: @Sundeep: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12742484/identify-overlapping-ranges-in-awk; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638951/how-to-remove-overlap-in-numeric-ranges-awk; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488613/awk-to-find-overlaps; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482040/using-awk-to-print-pairs-of-records-having-overlapping-range-of-values-between-t; There was another one not found on stackoverflow but I can't find it again.

Comment: you can link them in question + add the variation you tried not present in those links...

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I looked at the data again but I don't see why it should, maybe I am missing something. In any case I actually missed one interval: `1125 1126`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it in awk.  There's likely a more efficient way.

```
awk '{b=e=0; for(i=$1; i<=$2; i++) { if (exists[i]) if(b==0) {b=e=i} else {e=i}; exists[i]=i; } if(b) print b,e; }' input_file
```